# my samsung galaxy w doesn't register on 2g network

Tags: connection-issues, mobile-network

I've tried factory reset and manual search but no solution for the problem 
it works on 
i have flashed this rom:

I8150JPLM7_I8150OJPLM4_I8150XXLMB,

and no solution.

Comment: Please update your question with a few more details (and care a little more for formatting): What Android version? What kind of ROM is that (cryptic numbers are not intuitive, though helpful -- but not everybody can tell what they mean)? Does it register on 3g? Further reading: [How To Ask Android Questions The Smart Way](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/16575)